# Showing system configuration form field as disabled

Tags: configuration, forms, system.xml

Can anyone tell my how I can show a select box field in the system configuration as disabled?

I want to have a status field that shows the status of a job (running/not running). When the value is "running" I want to show a button that can stop the job.

My current approach is to have a `<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>` for the status and the button uses `<depends>` in order to decide if it is shown or not.
So far this works as expected. 
But I don't want the select to be editable. `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select` checks for attributes like `readonly` and `disabled` but how can I activate them?
Is there a simple solution besides writing a custom frontend_model?

As a sidenote: I would not need a select box to do this. A label would be more than enough. Unfortunately the Magento's `form.js` seems to stick to `input` or `select` when checking `depends`

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify a frontend model to your field like this:

```
<field_name translate="label">
    <label>Field name</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <frontend_model>module/field_name_renderer</frontend_model><!-- this is it -->
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</field_name>
```

Now you have to create the class for that frontend model. This is not actually a model it's a block.

```
<?php 
class Namespace_Module_Block_Field_Name_Renderer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field{
    protected function _getElementHtml($element) {
        if (YOUR CONDITION HERE) {
            $element->setDisabled('disabled');
        }
        return parent::_getElementHtml($element);
    }
}
```

As for side note...I have no idea...yet.

Comment: Thanks Marius. Beside accepting this as the correct answer: Can you tell me where exactly the Varien_Data_Form_Element is created? Just curious :)

Comment: @Celldweller. I'm not sure I understand what you mean but I will shoot in the dark with this `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form::initFields`

Comment: Hit! I guess... ;-) Thx!

Comment: you should wrap the code and if inside a method :)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. Thanks. I got all excited about the code that I forgot the method name. :)